# how to use ansible b64encode

Tags: base64, ansible

I need to do base64 encoding of something like: "https://myurl.com". Because there is a colon in that string, I need to enclose everything in quotes. So I have something like:

```
- name: do the encode
  shell: 'echo "https://myurl.com" | /usr/bin/base64'
  register: bvalue
```

But I get a blank when I use:

```
{{ bvalue.stdout }}
```

So I want to use the Ansible construct, but I don't know how and the documentation is not clear. It's something like:

```
- name: do the encode
  shell: '{{ "https://myurl.com" | b64encode }}'
```

But I *know* that is wrong. And I can't find any examples. Help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think this is how to do it. Define a variable in a playbook:

```
MYVAR: "https://myurl.com"
```

Then in the role, do:

```
- name: do the encode
  shell: echo {{ MYVAR | b64encode }} > /tmp/output
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ansible's [`b64encode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/b64encode_filter.html) filter:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ 'https://myurl.com' | b64encode }}"
```

```
TASK [my_playbook : debug] **********************************************
ok: [my_host] => {
    "msg": "aHR0cHM6Ly9teXVybC5jb20="
}
```